# Simple Node.js server no data received from post.

Tags: node.js, post

I have set up a simple server in Node.js. I am trying to get the post data from the request. I have tried sending the data with `$.post()` and by a simple HTML form with `method="post"`

```
if(request.method.toUpperCase() === "POST") {
    var $data;
    request.on("data", function (chunk) {$data += chunk});
    request.on("end", function () 
        console.log($data);
    });
    var message = "Settings Saved"
    response.writeHead(
        "200",
        "OK",
        {
            "access-control-allow-origin" : origin,
            "content-type" : "text/plain",
            "content-length" : message.length
        }
    );
    return(response.end(message));
}
```

Node returns the Status:200 and everything looks good, but no matter where I put it, the `console.log($data)` always spits out `undefined` (BTW I have also tried this without the `$` under a different variable name).

Looking at all the other SO questions about this that I could find did not have a solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `var $data = '';`

not `var $data;`

```
var $data; // $data === undefined. 
//...
$data += chunk // undefined + 'string' === 'undefined'
```

Comment: any recommendation how I can get the value off of each object? So if the post has a text field `name="background"` and I type "green" in it. The `$data` then contains `background=green` so how do I get the value? `$data.background`?

Comment: assume $data contains `background=green,otherKey=otherValue`

https://gist.github.com/poying/5942824